# Shifting specific elements in a logical array

Tags: matlab

So I have this matrix:

```
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 0     1     1
```

I don't know what statement(s) I have to write to change the bottom row only so that it becomes:

```
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 1     0     1
```

Specifically, I'd like to swap the 1st and 2nd column of of the 7th row only.

Not only that but I'd like to write a statement that finds adjacent 1's value in a row such as 1 1 0 or 0 0 0 1 1 0 and then applies the same switching.

Comment: This is too unclear, any useful answer would require some information on what governs hat change. Are you trying to left-shift the bottom row? In that case have a look at MATLAB's `circshift` function. To isolate the bottom row, assuming your matrix is called `M`, use `M(end,:)` so something like `M(end,:) = circshift(M(end,:),1)`

Comment: Hi Dan, I'd like to swap the 1st and 2nd column of of the 7th row only. Not only that but I'd like to write a statement that finds adjacent 1's value in a row such as 1 1 0 or 0 0 0 1 1 0 and then applies the same switching. Thnks heaps.

Comment: What does the same switching mean for the second case? You want to swap the first `0` with the second `0`? If you are asking how to swap two elements of a matrix then I think your question is off topic as being too specific (and honestly, utterly trivial). But Drorco's answer answers you exactly so why isn't his accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the variable mat represents your matrix. use:

```
mat(7,[1,2]) = mat(7,[2,1]);
```

Where 7 specifies the row which you want to perform the swapping on, and 1 and 2 are the columns to swap.

Comment: Hi droco, This would work. However, I'd like to write a statement that finds any 1's value that are adjacent of each other as well. This is because it is part of a bigger function and I can't manually find them every time. Is there a circshift combination that would let me swap only the 1st and 2nd column of the 5th row? Thnks heaps

Comment: simply write 7 instead of end, I updated my answer. Did it work for you?